# Plugin Variable can't find template

Tags: plugin-development

I'm new to Craft template development and one of the first things I'm trying to do is create a `Variable` that renders a template into the template its called from.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
/craft
  /plugins
    /test
      /templates
        _headers.html
      /variables
        TestVariable.php
```

Here is the Variable:

```
<?php

namespace Craft;

class TestVariable
{
    /**
     * Get header for test code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function headers()
    {
        return craft()->templates->render('test/_headers');
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it in the template with a simple: `{{ craft.test.headers }}`

My template is erroring with `Unable to find the template “test/_headers”.`

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: I ran into this issue yesterday, and I too am unsure of the answer. What I did find out is that when you try to render templates from the front-end, it looks to the front-end /templates directory for the Craft install, not the directory for your plugin. If there is a way to render templates from the plugin directory, I too would like to know. But looking through the code for a bit, I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/templates is very unclear about where `craft()->templates->render('test/_headers');` can be called from for plugins. It can definitely be called from the base plugin PHP, but beyond that I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

Just added this note to the [Plugin Templates](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/templates) documentation, which should answer your question:

> Craft will only automatically look for templates within the plugin folders for CP requests. If you are going to be calling TemplatesService::render() from a front end site request, you will need to manually tell Craft where to find your template using [PathService::setTemplatesPath()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/apis/pathservice#setTemplatesPath) first:
>
> ```php
> $oldPath = craft()->path->getTemplatesPath();
> $newPath = craft()->path->getPluginsPath().'pluginHandle/templates';
> craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($newPath)
> $html = craft()->templates->render('path/to/template');
> craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($oldPath);
> ```
>
> If you do this, you won’t be needing to begin the template path with your plugin handle.

Comment: Thanks, Brandon. I still couldn't get this code to work (`Unable to find the template “_headers”.`), and its a lot of code for what we're trying to accomplish, so I just included the entire template in the `Variable` as a string and used `return craft()->templates->renderString($headerTemplateString);` instead.